# Getting an error when tried to scrape data from instagram

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram

I am trying to use `instagramy` python package to scrape some instagram data, by following this tutorial: https://pypi.org/project/instagramy/

I used following lines of code (I have used a fake seesion id in this post)

```
from instagramy import InstagramUser
s_id="55449%3APUiRY9UGd7JMJO%3A2uFFQSOlJinJd3dGKGGsAOvBNzTg"
profile = InstagramUser('google',sessionid=s_id)
```

But I got following error:

[image]

Could anybody help me to figure out what is causing this error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like instagram has changed its api, and the library doesn't work anymore therefore [github-issue](https://github.com/yogeshwaran01/instagramy/issues/30)

Maybe @thiindolentone his [comment](https://github.com/yogeshwaran01/instagramy/issues/30#issuecomment-1177257059) helps you:

> ```py
> from instaloader import Instaloader, Profile
>
> PROFILE = "username"
>
> L = Instaloader()
>
> profile = Profile.from_username(L.context, PROFILE)
>
> print(profile.followers)
> ```
>
> subsitute followers for followees for followees
>
> for profile you will need to log in. For more info, see
>
> https://instaloader.github.io/